# matlab returns values as 1.0e+04 * something, how to get the final value?

Tags: matlab

Matlab returns values as

1.0e+04 * 
[matrix here]

some of the values inside the matrix are 0.1981, 0.5765, etc...

How to get the answer in this representation
1981, 5765, etc... instead of 1.e+04 *

Comment: I think `format longG` is the best view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the format. Try

```
 format long
```

and then check your output. There are other format options you can use if this is not what you want http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/format.html

Comment: The approach is correct but it's not `format long`. Try `format long; A = 1e5 * rand(5)` and see for yourself.

Comment: @EitanT  Yes I dont actually have matlab in front of me so I could not check, just trying to  point the OP in the right direction with the link and the `format`

Answer (score 7):

This is actually just MATLAB's way to display the output. You have to use the [`format`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html) command to change the display formatting, like this:

```
format bank
```

This should force MATLAB to display the numbers with precision of two places after the decimal point.

To revert to the default formatting, just type:

```
format
```

**Example:**

```
A = 1e5 * rand(2)
A =

  1.0e+004 *

    7.4701    9.7694
    9.7517    6.7675

format bank
A

A =

  74700.70      97693.76
  97516.71      67675.22
```

P.S.

If your matrix contains only integers, you can use `uint32(A)` or `uint64(A)` too:

```
B = ceil(A);
uint32(B)

ans =
       74701       97694
       97517       67676
```