# small differences between large or tiny numbers

Tags: matlab

I have a data of small numbers which have small differences. As matlab cut the numbers from the first 4 digit, all numbers seem to be equal. Could you please tell me how to more calculate sensitively?
For example:

```
10000000000

ans =

   1.0000e+10

>> 10000000001

ans =

   1.0000e+10
```

Comment: These numbers are not small at all... are you familiar with the [_scientific notation_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)? In this notation, MATLAB displays only the most significant digits, it doesn't affect calculations in any way, the numbers remain the same. Use [`format long`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) to change the display format (see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12035559)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab is calculating with all the significant figures you give it (up to 16 digits). It is just displaying only the most significant digits. It defaults to `format short` (or `format short e` for numbers that are too large to display with `format short`), which displays 5 significant digits. As @Eitan T noted, `format long` or `format long e` will display 15 digits.

Comment: thank you for your response. How can I let Matlab calculate for more than 16 digits? Is it possible to calculate for 50 digits?

Comment: Certainly. You can use [variable precision arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/symbolic/vpa.html) from the Symbolic Math Toolbox.

Comment: You can use sprintf to get use non scientific notation. E.g.:
100000000001.0001;sprintf('%.4f',ans)